# Immutable update of nested array records

Tags: flutter, dart, immutability, deep-copy

I am using dart and Freezed package for creating our data models which are as follow:

```
@freezed
abstract class Company with _$Company {
      factory Company({String name, KtList<Director> directors}) = _Company;
}   

@freezed
abstract class Director with _$Director {
      factory Director({String name, ktList<Assistant> assistants}) = _Director;
}

@freezed
abstract class Assistant with _$Assistant {
     factory Assistant({String name, int age}) = _Assistant;
}
```

If I have an object(or reference) for Assistant as **assistant** and if I want to update the age of assistant(e.g from 25 to 30 and we cannot do it like assistant.age = 30), what would be the best approach.

I think I have to first identify the location of the assistant in the model tree and make a deep copy. But I am unable to figure out the efficient algorithm for finding the location of the object.

I am new to the immutable programming please help me to solve this problem.